# git exclude everything except specific folder and its content

Tags: git

```
*

!README.md

!/code/local/
!/code/local/*

!/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/
!/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/*
```

tried using solutions found online, got above, when I do `git add .`

nothing is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist folders before whitelisting files:

```
**
!**/

!README.md

!/code/local/*

!/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/*
```

Note: use `local/**` (instead of `local/*`) if you want to exclude files in subfolders of `local/`

You can check the effect of a `.gitignore` with [`git checkignore -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```

Comment: that works, thanks, all conditions are straight forward, but I don't quite get why I need `!**/`

Comment: @Eudemon Because an ignored folder means any elements underneath that folder are ignored too, even if you whitelist those files. So whitelists folders first, then you can whitelist files.